# HOW TO COUNT CONSECUTIVE NON WORKING DAYS TO IMPOSE PENALTY

Tags: sql

HERE IS THE SAMPLE DATA -DATE WISE

```
EMPL    1052017 2052017 3052017 4052017 5052017 6052017 7052017 8052017 9052017 10052017    11052017    12052017    13052017    14052017    15052017    'PENALTY > 3'

EMP1        P   A   A   A   A   P   P   A   A   A   A   A   P   P   P   3

EMP2        A   A   P   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   P   A   P   P   A   4

EMP3        A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   12
```

HELP IN SQL TO GET CONSECUTIVE NON PRESENT DAYS AS PENALTY DAYS ...
LOGIC : CONTINUOUSLY MORE THAN 3 ABSENTS THEN 1 PENALTY, IF 5 DAYS THEN 2 PENALTY,IF 6 THEN 3 AND GO ON.

REQUIRED RESULT AS BELOW

```
EMPL     P.DAYS         A.DAYS        PENALTY

EMP1       6              9             3

EMP2       3             11             4

EMP2       0             15            12
```

Comment: Caps lock stuck?

Comment: Please read [ask], remove the caps, and improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ms sql-server, you can use this approach.

I assume your table keeps the values as vertical like this.

```
-- Create Table & Sample Data
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(
    EMPL VARCHAR(10), 
    Value VARCHAR(10),
    [Date] DATETIME )

INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
('EMP1', 'P', '20170501'),
('EMP1', 'A', '20170502'),
('EMP1', 'A', '20170503'),
('EMP1', 'A', '20170504'),
('EMP1', 'A', '20170505'),
('EMP1', 'P', '20170506'),
('EMP1', 'P', '20170507'),
('EMP1', 'A', '20170508'),
('EMP1', 'A', '20170509'),
('EMP1', 'A', '20170510'),
('EMP1', 'A', '20170511'),
('EMP1', 'A', '20170512'),
('EMP1', 'P', '20170513'),
('EMP1', 'P', '20170514'),
('EMP1', 'P', '20170515'),
('EMP2', 'A', '20170501'),
('EMP2', 'A', '20170502'),
('EMP2', 'P', '20170503'),
('EMP2', 'A', '20170504'),
('EMP2', 'A', '20170505'),
('EMP2', 'A', '20170506'),
('EMP2', 'A', '20170507'),
('EMP2', 'A', '20170508'),
('EMP2', 'A', '20170509'),
('EMP2', 'A', '20170510'),
('EMP2', 'P', '20170511'),
('EMP2', 'A', '20170512'),
('EMP2', 'P', '20170513'),
('EMP2', 'P', '20170514'),
('EMP2', 'A', '20170515'),
('EMP3', 'A', '20170501'),
('EMP3', 'A', '20170502'),
('EMP3', 'A', '20170503'),
('EMP3', 'A', '20170504'),
('EMP3', 'A', '20170505'),
('EMP3', 'A', '20170506'),
('EMP3', 'A', '20170507'),
('EMP3', 'A', '20170508'),
('EMP3', 'A', '20170509'),
('EMP3', 'A', '20170510'),
('EMP3', 'A', '20170511'),
('EMP3', 'A', '20170512'),
('EMP3', 'A', '20170513'),
('EMP3', 'A', '20170514'),
('EMP3', 'A', '20170515')
```

For determining consecutive absences you can use this query.

```
;WITH CTE AS ( 
    SELECT  
        ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMPL ORDER BY [Date]) ) 
        -  ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMPL, Value ORDER BY [Date]) ) AS GRP
        , * 
    FROM @MyTable
),
CTE_GRP AS (
    SELECT EMPL, Value, GRP, COUNT(*) CNT 
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY EMPL, Value, GRP 
)
SELECT EMPL,
    SUM( CASE WHEN Value ='P' THEN CNT ELSE 0 END ) [P.DAYS],
    SUM( CASE WHEN Value ='A' THEN CNT ELSE 0 END ) [A.DAYS],
    SUM( CASE WHEN (CNT - 3) > 0 THEN CNT - 3 ELSE 0 END) PENALTY
FROM
    CTE_GRP
GROUP BY EMPL
```

Result:

```
EMPL       P.DAYS      A.DAYS      PENALTY
---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
EMP1       6           9           3
EMP2       4           11          4
EMP3       0           15          12
```

Comment: I'm curious, how you think your answer can possibly be helpful. Do you really think the OP is going to understand the complexity of what you posted? You also have no context regarding the question (is it a homework assignment? Is it really SQL Server vs a different database engine?). The OP showed zero work, and has no specific question aside from "write code for me."

Comment: You are right, I made some assumptions and it makes my answer little bit complex. I made some update. Thank you for your notices.

Comment: Not sure your updates helped: Now you've added your own table model. Honestly, it's best to let the OP be more specific, vs spending time inventing answers based on complete unknowns.